# WebView is clipping the webpage in android 4.4

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

WebView is clipping the webpage on Android 4.4. Here is how it looks:
[image: In WebView]

It is opening correctly in google chrome. I want it to open like this in the webview.
[image: In Chrome]

Following is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView=findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView .getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView .getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://viftbox.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely the site is using modern HTML5/CSS features. Android 4.4 was the last OS version where the WebView was not independently upgradeable. Easiest fix would be to set the minSDK to 21 (Lollipop).

Comment: don't know why but it works normally on my device

Comment: @MorrisonChang The problem is that the app is being made to work on a tablet with Android 4.4. Is there any way I could use chromium based webview on Android 4.4?

Answer (score 1):

For using a recent WebView engine on Android and you can't use Android System WebView or Google Chrome:

Prior to Android 5.0 improvements to the Android WebView was limited to OS upgrades/updates. So the recommendation was to use the **NOW DEPRECATED** [Crosswalk Project](https://github.com/crosswalk-project) as the WebView. While the site no longer exists, [its ghost exists on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20171123024847/https://crosswalk-project.org/) I don't know if enough of the site survives there to be useful. This might be a solution if you are unable to change hardware and need more recent webkit features.

As the Crosswalk Project is no longer updated, or it doesn't have the features you need, I've learned that Mozilla has a [GeckoView](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView) which wraps their Gecko render engine.

Note that according to Mozilla's documentation they have their own APIs so GeckoView is **NOT** a drop-in replacement for Android's WebView, so some effort must be made for integration.

Either way including a custom webview engine will add to the APK size.