# Web view in KITKAT Video autoplay not working only show the thumbnail

Tags: java, android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

Setting of webview

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
            webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        }
        webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
         myWebview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
        webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");

      webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);

        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }


        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientCustomPoster());

        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 5 Build/_BuildID_) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36");
```

But web view to show the only thumbnail of the video Problem only in kitkat

Comment: KitKat is old. Double check the video encoding format. As WebView code is tied to KitKat OS version if you are connecting to a site that you have no control over, there are limited options depending on what you are try to do & device environment. Providing a logcat when failing might help.

Comment: may be this creates issue  Access denied finding property "acodec.video.buflogging"

or  [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined", 

or may be this evaluateJavascript=javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()

Comment: You should specify what hardware you are testing on. While sounds similar not sure if relevant: [Android KitKat (4.4) video autoplay does not work anymore in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20673533/295004)

Comment: Hardware is Android Tv Daiwa Supportive version Android 4.4.2

Comment: Does WebView auto play video on different Android 4.4 hardware - like a Nexus 4 or Samsung device running 4.4? If so then TV ODM issue. Or site is using modern HTML5 which doesn't work on old WebView. If you are required to get it working, one alternative is to switch out the webview engine with something more modern as I suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62279121/295004) but video playing is unknown, and APK size gets large.